# Python Backpropagation - How to Initialize the starting activation?

Tags: python, networking, neural-network, backpropagation

I am having some troubles implementing this backprop network. I'm not really understanding how to start this off because in this network my first layer only has 8 nodes. But my prompt gives me 10 in the training set.

In the first group for example, I have

```
[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
```

but only 8 nodes so I can assign a starting activation for each node or I would have 2 left over.

```
#######################################################################################
# 
#                               Preparations 
# 
#######################################################################################

import random
import math
import pygame
import sys
network1 = []
network2 = []
layer1 = []
layer2 = []
layer3 = []
set1 = []
set2 = []
set3 = []
mu = .5
eta = .1

#######################################################################################
# 
#                                   Node Class
# 
#######################################################################################

class Node(object): 

    def __init__(self,name=None): 
        self.name = name
        self.error = None
        self.activation_threshold = 0.0
        self.net_input = 0.0
        self.net_output = 0.0
        self.outgoing_connections = [] 
        self.incoming_connections = []
        self.activation = None

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def addin(self,sender,weight=random.random):
        self.incoming_connections.append(Connection(sender,self,weight=random.random))
    def addout(self,sender,weight=random.random):
        self.outgoing_connections.append(Connection(sender,self,weight=random.random)) 

    def update_input(self): 
        self.net_input=0.0
        for conn in self.incoming_connections:
            self.net_input += conn.weight * conn.sender.activation

    def update_output(self): 
        self.net_output=0.0
        for conn in self.outgoing_connections: 
            self.net_output += conn.weight * self.activation

    def update_activation(self):
        self.activation = 1 / (1 + math.exp(-self.net_input))

    def update_weight(self):
        for i in self.incoming_connections:
            i.weight = (2*i.reciever.activation - 1)*(2*i.sender.activation-1)
        for i in self.outgoing_connections:
            i.weight = (2*i.reciever.activation - 1)*(2*i.sender.activation-1)

    def update_error(self):
        pass

#######################################################################################
# 
#                                   Connection Class
# 
#######################################################################################

class Connection(object): 
    def __init__(self, sender, reciever, weight=random.random): 
        self.weight=weight 
        self.sender=sender 
        self.reciever=reciever

    def __str__(self):
        string = "Connection from " + str(self.sender) + " to " + str(self.reciever) + ", weight = " + str(self.weight)
        return string

#######################################################################################
# 
#                                     Creating Nodes & Connections 
# 
#######################################################################################

for i in xrange(8): 
    layer1.append(Node(str(i)))
network1.append(layer1)
for i in xrange(3):
    layer2.append(Node(str(i)))
network1.append(layer2)
for i in xrange(8): 
    layer3.append(Node(str(i)))
network1.append(layer3)

for i in xrange(8):
    for j in xrange(3):
        layer1[i].addin(layer2[j])
for i in xrange(3):
    for j in xrange(8):
        layer2[i].addin(layer3[j])

#######################################################################################
#
#                                         Training Patterns
#
#######################################################################################

"""Non-Overlapping Categories"""
cata11=[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
set1.append(cata11)
cata12=[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]
set1.append(cata12)
catb11=[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0]
set1.append(catb11)
catb12=[0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
set1.append(catb12)
catc11=[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]
set1.append(catc11)
catc12=[0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
set1.append(catc12)
catd11=[0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
set1.append(catd11)
catd12=[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
set1.append(catd12)

"""Linearly Independent Instances and Linearly Separable Categories"""
cata21=[1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]
set2.append(cata21)
cata22=[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]
set2.append(cata22)
catb21=[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0]
set2.append(catb21)
catb22=[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0]
set2.append(catb22)
catc21=[1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]
set2.append(catc21)
catc22=[1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]
set2.append(catc22)
catd21=[1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
set2.append(catd21)
catd22=[1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
set2.append(catd22)

"""Not Linearly Separable Categories"""
cata31=[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
set3.append(cata31)
cata32=[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
set3.append(cata32)
catb31=[1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]
set3.append(catb31)
catb32=[0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0]
set3.append(catb32)

##set_activations(cata11)
for i in network1:
    i.update_weight()
##for thing in node1:
##    thing.update_weight()
##set_activations(cata12)
##for thing in node1:
##    thing.update_weight()
##set_activations(catb11)
##for thing in node1:
##    thing.update_weight()
##set_activations(catb12)
##for thing in node1:
##    thing.update_weight()
##set_activations(catc11)
##for thing in node1:
##    thing.update_weight()
##set_activations(catc12)
##for thing in node1:
##    thing.update_weight()
##set_activations(catd11)
##for thing in node1:
##    thing.update_weight()
##set_activations(catd12)
##for thing in node1:
##    thing.update_weight()

#######################################################################################
#
#                                        Updating Network
#
#######################################################################################

for i in layer1:
    i.update_input()
    print 'Node', str(i), 'Input : ', i.net_input
for i in layer1:
    i.update_activation()
    print 'Act:', i.activation
for i in layer1:
    i.update_output()
    print 'Output', i.net_output
for i in layer2:
    i.update_input()
    print 'Node', str(i), 'Input : ', i.net_input
for i in layer2:
    i.update_activation()
    print 'Act:', i.activation
```

Answer (score 0):

## Neural network structure

I believe you've misunderstood how the neural network structure is build up. All of your input values should be sent to all the neurons in the subsequent layer. Thus all of your 10 input signals should be sent to all 8 of the neurons. Please see the appended graphics. I've only included the connections for a few of the neurons to make the drawing easier to understand.

### Graphical representation

[image]